# Close option for questions that can be answered with a simple research

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I think that close options on Stack Overflow aren't complete. Ok, in off-topic options there's still an "other" option, but it's too bad that other users don't see the reason, but just see a comment posted below.

I think that there should be more options like: "this question can be answered with a simple research", maybe written in a more elegant and gentle way but that explain the concept.

Comment: All questions can be solved using the internet and time. Who decides what level of too simple is *too* simple. If its just a definition then I think its already off topic. If its on topic and not a duplicate but simple its if anything a very good thing its on stack overflow because the simple questions help the most people

Comment: What's wrong with "Off Topic: Must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem"?

Comment: Related discussion here: [Why reward an answer to a low quality question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185458/why-reward-an-answer-to-a-low-quality-question/185461#comment568087_185461)

Comment: @RichardTingle I think that discretion is still valuable through Stack Overflow users. I also disagree that all questions can be solved using a research, maybe a great part of them can be used doing a research. But not with a simple research, which is the case I want to treat in this question: a question for things that have already hundreds of guides and tutorial on the web.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri All questions can be answered with a search on the internet. Should we close all of Stack Overflow's questions with this new option ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I already answered to this in the comment above.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Closing options should **not** be depending on the interpretation of a user on certain rules. It should be clear when you see a question whether it should be closed or not. Is it a duplicate ? No! Is it a real question ? Yes!  Is it off topic ? No. Is it overly broad ? No! Can it be solved by a **simple** search on the internet ? (Does it have 100 tutorials) .. eh.. wait.. I count 2 or 3.. hum.. I searched for..10 minutes... is that simple.. no.. wait.. long search.. damn...

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd But all what you are describing is biased on interpretation. Even if a question is duplicate or not may be biased on interpretation, since the problem may be considered different for some details form a similar question found on SO. If closing options should not depend on interpretation there were no closing options at all, unless something like "question too long, more than 10000 characters", which is the only deterministic thing that we can say.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about here is often refered to as *Proof of efforts*. 
Now, honestly, do you really need something more than this :

> [image]

If the user does not understand, does not show proof of efforts (searches, tries, fails) or simply fails to explain the problem properly, he obviously didn't searched at all before posting here.

If you feel this option is not good enough (doubtful but still..) you have the *other* where you can freely express how you feel about the lack of search of the OP.

As stated in the comments, adding an option "Can be solved by a simple research" would be bad. Who would choose what is a *simple* search and was isn't. Also if you give it time, any questions could be answered with the internet.

Comment: Why not a separate option? I think it's a different case. Not making a research does not mean that you don't have a minimal understanding of the problem.

Comment: No but not understanding, not showing searches or tries means you didn't search. Now, if the user understands, show the code, asks the question properly, shows what he tried and where he failed and the expected results then I'm sorry but no matter how obvious the answer is to you, it's a totally valid question. (Must be sure it's not a duplicate first though)

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: By the way, we usually say "doing research", not "making a research" or "with a research." You can also say "making a search"